# Recover from server down with Observable stream on a timer in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular 4 app where data on the screen is refreshed periodically using a timer:

```
getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return Observable.timer(0, 30000).switchMap(() => {
        this.lastUpdate = new Date();
        return this.activeDataStream;
    });
}
```

The activeDataStream is defined as:

```
    if (this.theUrl) {
        this.activeDataStream =
            <Observable<Data[]>>this.http.get(
                this.theUrl, this.options)
                .map(resp => {
                    return this.extractData(resp);
                })
                .share();
```

In my subscriber, I consume this stream:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSubscriber = this.myService.getData()
    .subscribe(
    data=> {
      this.group = this.summarizeData(data);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.dataSubscriber.unsubscribe();
}
```

if the server (.net WebApi REST service) goes down, the stream continues to try to get data every 30 seconds. When the server comes back, it seems like the subscribers have disconnected. Is there any good way to prevent this disconnection or to reconnect? Now the user has to realize their data is old and hit F5.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used observable timers myself, but can't you simply use setInterval() ?

Comment: You are going to have to show more of your code.  What is `activeDataStream`?

Comment: Updated to show the activeDataStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call `getData()` in `ngOnInit()` you probably want to make a single subscription when the component is created.
Now it depends what's `this.activeDataStream` (is it a Subject or is it something like `this.http.get(...)`? You might be affected by Subject's internal state https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/rxjs-subjects-and-their-internal-state-7cfdee905156)

Anyway when a source Observable throws an error the chain is disposed and it will never ever produce anything unless you subscribe again. For this reason you can use for example `retry()` that listens only to `error` notifications and automatically resubscribes:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSubscriber = this.myService.getData()
    .retry()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.group = this.summarizeData(data);
    });
}
```

You can also silently ignore the error with `.catch(() => Observable.never())`

Comment: Sometimes there is a simple solution that you just don't know about. The retry method worked perfectly, thanks!